# Symfony/Twig not translating correctly when using message placeholders

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

I'm trying to use message placeholders with Twig template engine. My `navlist.it.yml` stores this message and its placeholder:

```
users:
  label: Gestione utenti %app%
```

And in my Twig template i'd like to pass app name as a string. So what i'm doing is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="nav-header">
        {{ 'users.label'|trans({'app' : 'Fid'}, 'navlist')|raw }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note i'm using `raw` because `users.label` may contain HTML. Output is exactly:

```
<li class="nav-header">Gestione utenti %Fid%</li>
```

So message is translated but extra `%...%` are added. What i'm missing?

Comment: Did you try with `{'%app%': 'Fid'}`?

Comment: @Maerlyn thank you, works. Feel free to add an answer if you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The percent signs are part of the pattern, so you should be adding them to the key of your translation values' array, like this:

```
{{ 'users.label'|trans({'%app%' : 'Fid'}, 'navlist')|raw }}
```

Comment: Also if you translate from within your controller via PHP, you may do something like `$page_title = $this->get('translator')->trans('Templates from category %category_title%',['%category_title%'=>$category_title]);`